# How to run NX Monorepo apps with "--inspect" flag to find Memory Leaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I'm hunting down a ghost in my Monorepo project that is being managed by `NX` and TypeScript.

In the past we'd used Javascript as follows: `node --inspect app.js` ,
but now I'm using `NX` as my Framework and running everything like this:
`nx serve my-app-name`.

How can we can `NX` with the flag `--inspect` to use Chrome Dev-Tools in `chrome://inspect` ?